# Batch file - wait for another commands

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

To [activate some commands from mozilla SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation) I have to run batch file called "activate".
I don't want to find the proper file each time I want to do something with this SDK, so I created batch file:

```
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\FirefoxAddOnSDK\addon-sdk-1.16\bin
activate
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\Firefox_AddOns\first_addon
```

I don't know batch very well, can you tell me **how can I tell computer to wait for another commands that I will type in that opened console?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start another CMD and wait for it:

```
dir
start /wait cmd
dir
```

The shell opens in its own window. When you are done you have to exit from it in order to continue batch execution.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to wait:

```
dir
dir
cmd
```

**UPDATE 2**

activate batch file was making the caller to end its execution too. The solution was:

```
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\FirefoxAddOnSDK\addon-sdk-1.16\bin
call activate
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\Firefox_AddOns\first_addon
cmd
```

Comment: I don't want to stop executing in the middle. I want the .batch file to execute all of its commands and then not to close itself.

Comment: Check the update...

Comment: still doesn't work :/ The CMD opens and after exectuting all commands, closes immediately

Comment: Are you sure the CMD is reaching the last line? The code you pasted is the actual code of your CMD file?

Comment: I'm not sure, because it closes too fast, but when I copy&paste this to cmd it works properly, so I think everything is ok

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Try the code. I updated it again.

Comment: so, it still doesn't work, but when I deleted "activate" line it's ok. But "activate" does its job correctly because, as I said, when I copy&paste this to cmd, everything works.

Comment: Is activate another CMD/BATCH file? If it is add start before it: "start /wait activate"

Comment: ok, works, but commands after it aren't executed ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14316/discussion-between-drk-com-ar-and-ludwik11)

Answer (score 0):

if you just insert "cmd" into your script at the appropriate moment then you will get a new prompt in the same window. After you enter any commands you should type "exit" and the script will continue. Just be aware that the script will be in the same directory as before the "cmd" was called.

```
*Previous part of the batch.*
cmd
*Put your commands in here and then type exit*
*Batch will continue here.*
```

Comment: I don't want to stop it during executing commands ;) Now it closes itself after ending doing what I typed in batch file. I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\FirefoxAddOnSDK\addon-sdk-1.16\bin
call activate
cd C:\Users\piotr_000\Documents\Firefox_AddOns\first_addon
:while1:
set /p "command=type in a command: "
:: do something here...
%command%
echo.press ^CTRL+C^ to exit.
>nul pause
goto :while1
```